# Modify shape as3

Tags: actionscript-3, line, shapes

Say I have a line drawn with several edges using Shape.graphics' moveTo() and lineTo() methods. Can I modify one of these edges later?   so for example:

```
var line:Shape = new Shape();
line.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, .75);

line.graphics.moveTo(10,10);              
line.graphics.lineTo(50,50); // Can I modify coordinates of the edge created on this line?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you can't. Once drawn there is no reference to the lines, so you can't modify them. You need to clear the graphics and redraw again.

Comment: pretty much what I was doing. Just wanted to make sure, thanks.